# Implement a class Person with two fields name and age, and a class Car with three fields

Tags: c++, pointers

Implementing a class Person with two fields name and age, and a class Car with three fields:

The model
A pointer to the owner (a Person*)

A pointer to the driver (also a Person*)

I am writing a program that prompts the user to specify people and cars. Store them in a vector and a vector. Traverse the vector of Person objects and increment their ages by one year. Traverse the vector of cars and print out the car model, owner s name and age, and driver s name and age.

This is my code so far i need some help about the program i don't know what is the error in this program anyone can anyone tell me please why it not displaying any output.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Person
{
  private:
  string name;
  int age;
  public:
  Person(string n, int a);
  string get_name()const;
  int get_age()const;
  void increment_age();
  void print()const;
};

Person::Person(string n, int a)
{ 
  name = n;
  age = a;
}

string Person::get_name() const
{
  return name;
}

void Person::increment_age()
{
  age += 1;
}

void Person::print() const
{
  cout << name << endl;
  cout << age << endl;
}


class Car
{
 private:
  string model;
  Person *owner;
  Person *driver;

 public:
  Car(string m);
  void set_driver(Person* p);
  void set_owner(Person* p);
  void print()const;
}; 


Car::Car(string m)
{
  model = m;
}

void Car::set_driver(Person* p)
{
  driver = p;
}

void Car::set_owner(Person* p)
{
  owner = p;
}

void Car::print() const
{
  cout << model << endl;
  cout << driver->get_name() << endl;
  cout << owner->get_name() << endl;
}



int main()
{ 
  vector<Person*> people;

  const int PERSON_SZ = 4;
  char * names[] = {"Jim", "Fred", "Harry", "Linda"};
  int ages[] = { 23, 35, 52, 59 };

  for (int i = 0; i < PERSON_SZ; i++)
  {
    Person *a = new Person(names[i], ages[i]);
    people.push_back(a);
  }

  vector<Car*> cars;
  const int CAR_SZ = 3;
  char * models[] = { "Festiva", "Ferrarri", "Prius" };

  for (int i = 0; i < CAR_SZ; i++)
  {
    Car *c = new Car(models[i]);
    c->set_driver(people[rand()% (people.size())]);
    c->set_owner(people[rand()% (people.size())]);
    cars.push_back(c);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Indent your code correctly, and for heaven's sake, tell us what your program actually does, in contrast to what you want it to do.

Comment: Help us all out a little: compile errors ? run-time errors ? A little more detail please...

Comment: Is this all the code? I see no main. You have to call the functions from somewhere if you want them to run...

Comment: "tell me please why it not displaying any output" - Because you don't print anything?

Comment: By the way, your `Car::print` function should probably be using `Person::print`.

Comment: Get into the habit of using constructor initializer lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your specific question: You are not printing anything.

Add this to your code

```
for (vector<Car*>::const_iterator iter = cars.begin(); iter != cars.end(); ++iter)
    (*iter)->print();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning name in get_name, you can print it right there.
Make string to void, & print name in get_name().
So instead of

```
cout<<driver->get_name();
```

you'll have to write

```
driver->getname();
```

same for owner.

Answer (score 0):

You can entrust the increment or output routines to the `std::for_each` statement. for_each applies the same action to every element in your container, or to a selected sequence.
It looks like:

```
void person_routine(Person* currentPerson)
{
    currentPerson->increment_age();
}

void cars_routine(Cars* currentCar)
{
    currentCar->print();
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<Person*> persons;
    std::vector<Cars*> cars;

    // fill both vectors

    for_each(persons.begin(), persons.end(), person_routine);
    for_each(cars.begin(), cars.end(), cars_routine);
}
```

Please check your code carefully and read your compiler output. You may always read about containers and algorithms at the http://cplusplus.com